# Create Lat+Long from a string?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1, geocode

In Windows Phone (mango) I am using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.

I currently have:

```
var _City = "Denver";
var _State = "Colorado";
```

And I want a pushpin:

```
var _Pushpin = new Pushpin();
_Pushpin.Location = new GeoCoordinate();
map1.Children.Add(_Pushpin);
map1.Center = _Pushpin.Location;
```

**How can I create the correct GeoCoordinate from the strings alone?**

Update with solution (using Bing):
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/10/bing-maps-geocoding.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways...

1) Get a Bing Maps API key and call into their web services to get the coordinates.  ([see here for an example](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#RESTServices1))
2) Have a local database of cities / states / coordinates to look up against.  This is probably the preferred option if the app must run offline, although in that case you wouldn't see the maps anyway.

Comment: Ended up using Bing. Easy as pie. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/10/bing-maps-geocoding.html